# Avoid executing custom commands in cmake when unnecessary

Tags: matlab, cmake

I have this custom build which invokes matlab to compile a .slx file into a .dll file.

```
function(BUILD_SIMULINK model)
   set(EXECUTE_COMMAND matlab -r "rtwbuild( ${model} )" )
   add_custom_target(
      ${model} ALL
      COMMAND           ${EXECUTE_COMMAND}
      DEPENDS           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${model}.slx
      OUTPUT            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${model}.dll
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
      COMMENT           "Building: ${model}"
   )
endfunction(BUILD_SIMULINK)
```

However my problem is that whenever I use `cmake --build .`, this command will always be executed.

How can I prevent this command from executing when the DEPENDS hasn't changed and the OUTPUT exists?  What I'm looking for is similar to how cmake avoids re-compiling c/cpp files when the source hasn't changed and the appropriate object file exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`add_custom_target()` command documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html):

> The target has no output file and is *always* considered out of date even if the commands try to create a file with the name of the target. Use the `add_custom_command()` command to generate a file with dependencies.

There is not `OUTPUT` keyword. I think its only accepted because CMake sees `OUTPUT` as a dependency. Actually I get an CMake warning when I run your code:

```
...
This project specifies custom command DEPENDS on files in the build tree
that are not specified as the OUTPUT or BYPRODUCTS of any
add_custom_command or add_custom_target:

 test_model.dll
```

You need to use `add_custom_command()`:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(TestCustomTargetWithDependency NONE)

function(BUILD_SIMULINK model)
   #set(EXECUTE_COMMAND matlab -r "rtwbuild( ${model} )" )
   set(EXECUTE_COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "${model}.dll")
   add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT            "${model}.dll"
      COMMAND           ${EXECUTE_COMMAND}
      DEPENDS           "${model}.slx"
      COMMENT           "Building: ${model}"
   )

   add_custom_target(
      ${model} ALL
      DEPENDS           "${model}.dll"
   )
endfunction(BUILD_SIMULINK)

file(WRITE "test_model.slx" "")
BUILD_SIMULINK(test_model)
```

: Sources/Dependencies default is `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` and outputs default is `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`. No need to explicitly prefix those.